# Best way to unset sessions in PHP

Tags: php, session

What is the difference and most secure way to clear login sessions in `PHP`? Basically going to call this when a user clicks `log out` in my application.

I am seeing:

```
 session_destroy()
 session_unset()
```

Or simply doing:

```
unset($_SESSION['my_key_1']);
unset($_SESSION['my_key_2']);
```

What is the best way?

Comment: Why do you need that? Garbage collector does that for you.

Comment: When a user clicks `log out`, I need to clear sessions completely.

Comment: Because otherwise they stay logged in.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

**session_destroy** is deleting whole session.

**session_unset** delete ony a variables from session - session still exist. Only data are truncated.

So, If you want to make memory free **session_destroy** is best.

Answer (score 1):

The best solution I know is to use `session_regenerate_id(true);`

This will drop the current session data and regenerate session id.

Assigning a new session id is a good idea because it will help to treat a user as a completely new one (in case if something in your code relies on session id).

Answer (score 1):

The `session_unset()` function frees all session variables currently registered. Meaning, it will do this:

```
unset($_SESSION);
$_SESSION = array();
```

The `session_destroy()` function will invalidate the whole session! The session hasn't took place.

Comment: `session_unset` right before `session_destroy` makes no sense.

Comment: nope, you copied the code from some stupid comment. Comments are not the part of manual and rarely a good place to learn